# javascript alert when mouseover Interactive leaflet Choropleth Map shape

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to generate a javascript alert with State name text (or store it in a variable) when user mouseover on interactive choropleth map poligons (like this map) http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

i try to store content of div class="info leaflet-control"  but without success

thanks a lot!

---

I create this jquery code thanks to this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener)

`$(".info.leaflet-control").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() { console.log($(".info.leaflet-control").find( "b" ).text()); });`

and works!

Comment: I create this jquery code and work! `$(".info.leaflet-control").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    console.log($(".info.leaflet-control").find( "b" ).text());
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about jQuery, and use Leaflet event handling, to attach an event handler to the `mouseover` event on the features you want to watch. The event received will hold all properties of the features that triggered the event.

See http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/buh/edit?html,output